# how to change setstate in map function runs for every time

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bots

How i can the state whenever my map fuction runs

I want to increase the count by 50 everytime my map function runs.

like map fetch one blog the count is now 50
second time the count is 100 and so on.

setstate:

const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

map function code:

```
    {blogs.slice(0).map((item) => {                
                    return <Link key={item.slug.current} href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                      <article className="ip oo ik" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay={`${count}`}>
                        <header>
                          <a href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                            <span className="ic re" href="blog-post.html">
                              <figure className="tq ig fe o_ oq">
                                <Image className="tj tz su ik an o lz ci cl" src={builder.image(item.mainImage).width().url()} layout='fill' sizes="50vw" priority='true' quality={60} alt={item.Alt} />
                              </figure>
                            </span>
                          </a>

<h3 className="h3 ra"> <span className="c_ lz cr cf text-hover text-2xl "><a href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>{item.title}</a></span> </h3>

                    </header>
                    <a href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                      <p className="fm li sz hover:text-black dark:hover:text-white">{item.metadesc}</p>
                    </a>
                    <footer className="ip ol rv"> <span>
                      {/* <Image className="oj sq rl" src="/" width="40" height="40" alt="Author 01" /> */}
                    </span>
                      <div className="fk"> <span className="lr c_ lz cr cf text-hover">{item.Name}</span> <span className="lc"> - </span> <span className="lf">{item.publishedAt}</span> </div>
                    </footer>

                  </article>

                </Link>
                
              })}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can derive the `count` value from the current `index` of the mapped element. Something like `const count = (index + 1) * 50`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with a state, since the map function is part of the render, and changing the state triggers a re-render, you'll end up in an infinite loop. You can try using `useRef` instead, not sure that will work for you:

```
const ref = useRef(0);

{blogs.slice(0).map((item) => {
  // However much you want to increase it, bear in mind this will add for every element in the array
  ref.current = ref.current + 50;
  return (<Link key={item.slug.current} href={"/blog-post/" + item.slug.current}>
                      <article className="ip oo ik" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay={`${count}`}>
    ...
  );
}}
```